# MySQL DUMP not importing.. SQL ERROR

Tags: windows, mysql

i have a Windows 2003 server with MySQL 5.5. I am attempting to import a MySQL dump, however a Syntax error is being generated on the table creates. When I try the same query on my Linux 5.1 installation, there is no problem.

The original data does not exist, so im somewhat stuck now..

```
CREATE TABLE `articledata` 
(
    `ID` integer (10) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `templateid` integer (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `issueid` integer (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `articletitle` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articletext` text NOT NULL, 
    `articlepic1` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articlepriority` integer (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `articledetails` text NOT NULL, 
    `articledetailstitle2` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articledetails2` text NOT NULL, 
    `articlepic2` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articledetailstitle` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articlepic1a` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `subclusterid` integer (11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Error is

```
ERROR 1064 <42000>: You have an error in your SQL syntax near: TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Comment: And the error you're getting is...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
# Notice Type should be Engine
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

The dump you are importing mostlikely comes from a different database which had a different setup. The character set specified I would assume is not valid is your current instance of mysql I would double check with this link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-server.html

You can try to remove the last part to become

```
CREATE TABLE `articledata` 
(
    `ID` integer (10) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `templateid` integer (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `issueid` integer (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `articletitle` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articletext` text NOT NULL, 
    `articlepic1` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articlepriority` integer (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    `articledetails` text NOT NULL, 
    `articledetailstitle2` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articledetails2` text NOT NULL, 
    `articlepic2` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articledetailstitle` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `articlepic1a` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `subclusterid` integer (11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

Which works fine here so it really is a character set configuration issue from your server.